# Fatal error: to change segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

my project is a simple app with a navigation bar and segue, I am getting this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)
```

in the line:

```
            cell.valueLabel.text = dictionary.word
```

Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100239474

The app run the first tableview in the iphone but when I touch any line of the table view to go to the next table view the app crash.
If I delete this switch the segue works and I can see the second view controller

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DefinitionTableViewCell

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell.fieldLabel.text = "wordLabel"
        cell.valueLabel.text = dictionary.word
    case 1:
        cell.fieldLabel.text = "meaningLabel"
        cell.valueLabel.text = dictionary.meaning
    default:
        cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
        cell.valueLabel.text = ""
    }

    return cell
}
```

Any help is more than welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you already created the `cell` in the `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`  like

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
```

Please check whether the type of `dictionary`, the instance of your DataModel (I guess), is `Optional`.

Comment: just update the question, if I delete the code for the switch the segue works....

Comment: 1. You can just assign a `String` to the `cell.valueLabel.text`, instead of an accession to the `dictionary`, to infer whether the error occurred in the `dictionary`.

Comment: 2. If it build&Run without error, which means you need to check your DataModel Class, `Dictionary` (I guess the name).